# Eclipse : Whether to select Local Or Shared File during Remote Debugging

Tags: eclipse

I have made some code changes and deployed the code to Jetty Server which is located Remotely .
Accessed the application through browser and I am trying to debug a Application .

Please tell me whether i need to select the Local File Or Shared File from the Eclipse Debug Configurations .

Please see the screen shot here .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option shown in your screenshot will not help you automatically get code deployed to your remote Jetty.

The option simply allows you to Share your launch configuration (Remote Java Application - ManageWatchlistCall) in your eclipse workspace. This will allow you to checkin the launch configuration in a versioning control system so your colleagues automatically get the sme Remote Java Application launch configuration.

in order to get new code to your remote server, there are only 2 options :

- Redeploy your application on the remote server.
- Hotdeploy  pieces of code to the remote supported (if the server supports it)
- Use Hotswap Bug Fixing (works for small fixes)  (*)

> (*) If you are running Java Virtual Machine (JVM) V1.4 or higher,
>   Eclipse supports a feature called Hotswap Bug Fixing (not available in
>   JVM V1.3 or lower). It allows the changing of source code during a
>   debugger session, which is better than exiting the application,
>   changing the code, recompiling, then starting another debugging
>   session. To use this function, simply change the code in the editor
>   and resume debugging.